# Data from fields in a group within a group in ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

i'm using Advanced Custom Fields to store data of people elected in municipal concils.
I'm using the following structure in my ACF plugin :

1. Group : Concil

   - Sub_group 1  : Elected_1

     - Field 1 : name
     - Field 2 : firstname
     - Field 3 : birthdate
     - Field 4 : jobtitle
     - Field 5 : gender
     - Sub_group 2  : Elected_2
     - Field 1 : name
     - Field 2 : firstname
     - Field 3 : birthdate
     - Field 4 : jobtitle
     - Field 5 : gender
       [...]
     - Sub_group 69  : Elected_69
     - Field 1 : name
     - Field 2 : firstname
     - Field 3 : birthdate
     - Field 4 : jobtitle
     - Field 5 : gender

I can have up to 69 elected in each post (but less for the majority of the cases.
I'm trying to make a loop in my child_theme file (wordpress) in order to display an HTML table with the info stored in the custom fields for each elected person (name, birthday, gender, jobtitle)

I'm new to Advanced Custom Fields and also to PHP development so here is my code based on other contribution and ACF documentation but for the moment it doesn't show anything (except the table head) but doesn't throw php/errors.

```
   <?php 
     $gender = 'gender';
     $name = 'name';
     $firstname= 'firstname';
     $birthdate = 'birthdate';
     $jobtitle = 'jobtitle';
     ?>


     <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th scope="col">Gender</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Birthday</th>
      <th scope="col">Jobtitle</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
      <?php 
    for ($i=1; $i<=69; $i++){
    if (have_rows('concil')) {
    while (have_rows('concil')) {
      the_row();} ?>

    <?php 
     while (have_rows('elected_'.$i)) {
        the_row();
        ${$gender.$i}  = get_field('gender');
        ${$name.$i}  = get_field('name');
        ${$firstname.$i}  = get_field('firstname');
        ${$birtdate.$i}  = get_field('birthdate');
        ${$jobtitle.$i}  = get_field('jobtitle'); 


       }?>
     <tr>
      <td><?php echo ${$gender.$i}; ?>  </td>
      <td><?php echo ${$name.$i}; ?> <?php echo ${$firstname.$i}; ?>  </td>
      <td><?php echo ${$birthday.$i}; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo ${$jobtitle.$i}; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php   }
    }
    ?>      
     </body>
     </table>
```

Do you know why this code doesn't work and/or a better solution to display this data in an html table ? 
Thanks for your help.
Regards

Comment: Did you try `get_sub_field('gender')` instead of `get_field('gender');`

Comment: basically - you are working with nested repeaters : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/working-with-nested-repeaters/ - So there is no need for `$i`

Comment: Hello Stender thanks for your reply. I'm not using repeaters but text fields.
My main group field (concil) has 69 subgroups which all contains the same textfields (name/firstname/gender/etc...)
I tried to change get_sub_field from get_field but it doesn't change anything. (the html table doesn not display)...